# Проблема с плавным переходом градиента кнопки "Оплатить" при наведении курсора в CSS

Tags: html, css, django, веб-программирование

Я разрабатываю сайт приема пожертвований для своего бота на Django и столкнулся с проблемой при работе с CSS. Я создал кнопку "Оплатить" с градиентом, и хотел, чтобы при наведении курсора на кнопку, она плавно переходила из одного градиента цвета в другой. Однако, плавность перехода не работает.

мой CSS код:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

form .submit-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    145deg,
    rgb(0, 0, 0) 0%,
    rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%
  );
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -o-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  transition: background-image 5.5s;
}

form .submit-button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    145deg,
    rgb(23, 6, 255) 0%,
    rgb(125, 230, 230) 100%
  );

  -webkit-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  -o-transition: background-image 5.5s;
  transition: background-image 5.5s;
}

#title {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    145deg,
    rgba(1, 135, 223, 1) 0%,
    rgba(0, 204, 204, 1) 100%
  );
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #f2eefb;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
a,
input {
  color: #017fe5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

p {
  cursor: default;
}

input,
button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #f2f7fc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

form label {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

form input[type="text"],
form input[type="number"],
form select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  form {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav a {
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a1c8d;
}
```

Django html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'generate_qiwi_link' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="vk_uid" name="vk_uid" required minlength="1" maxlength="50" placeholder="Введите ваш ID ВКонтакте"><br><br>
        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" required min="10" max="15000" placeholder="Введите сумму"><br><br>
        <label for="payment_system">Выберите платежную систему:</label>
        <select id="payment_system" name="payment_system" required>
            <option value="qiwi">Qiwi</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Оплатить" class="submit-button">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Можете ли вы подсказать, что я делаю не так и как правильно реализовать плавный переход градиента при наведении на кнопку? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно средствами "linear-gradient" и "background-position".
"--btn-width" - ширина кнопки, учитывая что она может быть любой мы пишем ширину в переменной и потом в "--bg-double" просто умножаем ширину background-а, а после этого с помощью "background-position-x" при наведении меняем на 100%.

```css
:root {
  --btn-width: 100%;
  --bg-double: calc(var(--btn-width) * 2)
}

.submit-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: var(--btn-width);
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 145deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0%,
  rgb(233 233 233) 50%,
  rgb(0 113 126) 100% );
  background-size: var(--bg-double);
  background-position-x: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 5.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.submit-button:hover {
  background-position-x: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="submit-button">Отправить</button>
```